# Devise: Use email field from parent table (has_one relationship)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have two models: Photographer and PhotographerCredential. A photographer has one credential.

There's already an email field in the Photographer model. I want to avoid duplication by using the email field in the parent table as the username for devise.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand why your need the second model, but your problem can be easily solved by setting an `email` method in the later.

```
class PhotographerCredential < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :photographer

  def email
    photographer.email
  end

  # No email= method. This attribute should be set at Photographer

end
```

Comment: Thanks, that was easier than I thought. My reasoning for doing it is that I have two forms to create Photographers. One is for the app admin, who needs to be able to create photographers without setting  a password. The other is a registrations form, to sign up as a photographer.